# AngularJS expression with HTML is adding quotes?

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to echo the following HTML expression (got it from decoded jSON):

```
<ion-item><a href="/category/latest-collection/women/dresses">Dresses</a></ion-item></ion-item>
```

Using this:

```
<ion-item-group *ngFor="let category of categories"><ion-item-divider color="light">{{category.name}}</ion-item-divider>{{category.links}}</ion-item-group>
```

But the result is:

```
<ion-item-group><ion-item-divider color="light">Women Clothes</ion-item-divider>&lt;ion-item&gt;&lt;a href="/category/latest-collection/women/dresses"&gt;Dresses&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/ion-item&gt;&lt;ion-item&gt;</ion-item-group>
```

Any ideas? :-(

Comment: If you want to render a string with html in it, you can use `<ion-item-divider [innerHTML]="category.name">`

Comment: When I use innerHTML it removes the `<ion-item>` tags...